# PHP MySQL Insert Help

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hey I am trying to make a page that inserts some strings into a MySQL table but it just dosn't seem to be working for me. Here is the code I am using at the moment.

```
<?php
mysql_connect($address, $username, $password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
$query = "insert INTO user (movieid, moviename)('" . $id . "','" . $name . "') or die(mysql_error())"; 
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no `die()` at all, but `trigger_error()` instead.
And data must be properly formatted for the query:

```
<?php
mysql_connect($address, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);

$id    = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$name  = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$query = "insert INTO user (movieid, moviename) VALUES ('$id','$name')"; 
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error((mysql_error().$query);
?>
```

Always do any mysql job this way

Answer (score 2):

- You have `or die` in the wrong place.
- You have omitted the VALUES keyword. See the documentation for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

The query should just be this:

```
"INSERT INTO user (movieid, moviename) VALUES ('" . $id . "','" . $name . "')";
```

The `or die` should come after the call to `mysql_query`.

You may also have an SQL injection vulnerability. Consider using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (movieid, moviename) VALUES ('" . $id . "','" . $name . "')";  
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```